# Axios django problem not response status in interceptor.response

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-401

```
// Add a 401 response interceptor
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    if (401 === error.response.status) {
        // handle error: inform user, go to login, etc
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

"Network Error" without any response
It was a problem with CORS and how it was setup, so axios never got the information back from the browser. You have to sort it out from the server side.

Comment: What error did you see in the JavaScript console? Adding that to your question will help others find this answer in the future.

Comment: Also, since this has to do with the Django backend, I recommend showing a `curl` request rather than the frontend JavaScript code. And if you don't know how to use `curl`, I highly recommend learning. It is a great tool for debugging and testing your API without writing your own (possibly buggy) frontend code.

Comment: What is your question? Looks like you are posting an answer as a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this problem and use Django add to setings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```